# What glue will stick ripstop polymide / nylon fabric together - e.g. patch on hole?

Tags: tents

I've got a tent with a hole in it. I've bought some ripstop waterproof nylon fabric. What glue will stick it on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contact cement is my go-to for most similar purposes.  It bonds well and is flexible to a large extent it should do well for your purposes.